# Apache Spark Task Serialization

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

This method gives me a Task Serialization Error:

```
def singleItemPrediction(userid : Int, item : Int) = {

  val userAndItems = useritemrating.filter({x => x._1 == userid && x._2 != item})

  val userMean = userAndItems.aggregate(0.0)((accum, rating) => accum + rating._3, _+_) / userAndItems.count()

  userMean + userAndItems.aggregate(0.0)((accum, ui) => accum + avgDev(userid, item, ui._2), _+_) / userAndItems.count()

}
```

Changing the bottom line (what's returned) to:

```
avgDev(userid, item1, item2), _+_) / userAndItems.count()
```

Does not give an error!

I do not understand why, what is the difference? It has something to do with the `avgDev` method being called with the `aggregate` action, but I'm not sure why this occurs. I keep having these problems and keep solving them, I'd like to know why they occur so I can stop making the same mistake and go through this scenario of fixing code over and over again.

Comment: Without seeing your complete relevant code (like the class) it's impossible to tell what is the problem. Something refers something that is not `Serializable`. Since you seem to be looking for a general method of debugging this sort of problem, that's what I answered with. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, it's helped, I've got my head around it now... I think! Thanks, Daniel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable serialization debugging with:

> -Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true

Comment: I get an error when I add this spark-submit option `--conf driver.extraJavaOptions -Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true`. Any ideas?